# How to make a playable DVD iso from a VIDEO_TS folder?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, video, script

I used to have a script that converts a VIDEO_TS folder into an ISO that plays ok in VLC but it's gone.

Anyway, this command gets me most of the way there:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -udf -udf-volume-name $folder -o $fullpath.iso $fullpath
```

Except that when I tried it on one DVD, it skips the menu selection. Is this likely a problem with the one DVD I tried or do I need a different tool / different options to get the menu to render properly?

Comment: Maybe better asked at http://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have always used Handbreak for doing this if you have the actual DVD and not a ripped copy of the VIDEO_TS. http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php not only does it work great, but it's updated regularly.

Comment: can you please enlighten me on how to make an ISO out of a DVD disc using handbrake? I've been using it for years and just checked now and I don't see such a feature. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just tried this on several VIDEO_TS and works perfectly.

```
hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -udf -udf-volume-name $folder -o $fullpath.iso $fullpath
```

ps. I've never found out how to make ISOs out of VIDEO_TS using handbrake. I don't think this is possible.