# enabling virtual machine Guest Additions on a Mac host and Mac guest

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I want to enable `Shared folders` on VirtualBox. I went to `Devices tab` and clicked -> `Insert guest additions CD image`. Nothing happened. This is an image of my Storage tab in Settings of Virtual box:

[image]

I previously got this message, that instructed me to go to `Insert guest additions CD image`:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll quote a [previous answer of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221639/142875):

> From [Virtualbox Manual : Chapter 14](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html):
>
> > **14.2. Known Issues**
> > Mac OS X guests:
> > VirtualBox does not provide Guest Additions for Mac OS X at this time
>
> [snip]
>
> From the content of [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=64921), I wouldn't hold out for such support in VirtualBox any time soon.

The situation really has not changed since then.

There is [some discussion of a workaround](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=58170) involving the built in OS X sharing functionality and configuring your network setup to work, but nothing well defined.

Comment: daamn, so no shared folders for Macs :(

Comment: Unfortunate, but I used Dropbox as a work-around which works fine. You can either use the same account on both your host and guest, or just set up a shared folder from one account to another. You could also use BitTorrent sync or something else.

Comment: I usually just use a USB key.

Answer (score 13):

Guest Additions are available for macOS starting with VirtualBox 6.0

Per the [change log](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog), macOS/OSX Guest Additions are at "initial support" meaning features/functionality could be limited.

Comment: it is a good news, Some one have tested it?

Answer (score 5):

Resolving this question involves having guest additions on a MacOS guest. If, instead, you want to install guest additions from a MacOS host onto a non-MacOS guest:
[You can copy the guest additions iso from your machine.](https://osquest.com/2012/11/13/tip-manually-installing-virtualbox-guest-additions/)

> First locate VirtualBox in the Application folder, right-click it and select show package contents. Then browse to Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso. Copy it to a location that accessible when browsing for files.

After that, you can insert the device by clicking Devices > Optical Drives > Choose disk image... and then choose your copied iso file.

Then you can run your iso from within your vm and install the guest additions.

Comment: What? I can't be this simple - have you done this and been able to do bidirectional drag and drop or clipboard sharing?

Comment: It worked for me. You have also to do this: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround: creating a `*.iso`

*([from here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125191/224888))*

Create a `*.iso` and insert this "optical drive".

- To create the file, open terminal and navigate to the folder you want to pack; then run: 
  `hdiutil makehybrid -iso -udf -udf-volume-name NAME_OF_ISO -o ./OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.iso ./FOLDER_TO_PACK/` 
  where obviously you have to choose `NAME_OF_ISO` (pretty much irrelevant), `OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.iso` and specify the folder `FOLDER_TO_PACK`
- Then insert the created file in your guest 
   [image]